# model item in WF 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm working in a WF 4.0 project. This is a part of my own custom activity:

```
public Activity Create(DependencyObject target)
{
        var sequenceModelItem = (target as WorkflowViewElement).ModelItem;
        sequenceModelItem
            .Properties["Variables"]
            .Collection
            .Add(new Variable<List<string>>("Provider", provider));

        sequenceModelItem
            .Properties["Variables"]
            .Collection
            .Add(new Variable<string>("ProviderSearch"));

        return new Sequence
        {
            Activities =
        {
           // Some activities...
        } 
        };
    }
```

So Here is the question. In provider I have a list< string > of some providers that i have in my DB. in SequenceModelItem I create a variable with the same type and i associate the list provider to there. Everything is correct, but when I deploy the workflow and Execute, the following error appeare:

***The following errors were encountered while processing the workflow tree: 'Literal<List <String>> ': Literal only supports value types and the immutable type System.String. The type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] cannot be used as a literal ***

For sure that the error is here:

```
    .Add(new Variable<List<string>>("Provider", provider));
```

But I don't know what I have to do to solve it,

Thanks!!

Comment: For future references, `<` will get stripped out if its not used in a code block.  You can use the standard escape instead `&lt;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you need to change that line to:

```
.Add(new Variable<Dictionary<string, object>>( { "Provider", provider }));
```

Based on [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/26/passing-arguments-to-workflow-activities-again.aspx) by Ron Jacobs, it appears that the new Variable is trying to convert your List to a Literal which would fail for references types (List).  The articles points that if you want to use a reference type you must use a Dictionary.

Comment: Hi ShelbyZ. When I do this a error in execution time appeare. Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "(Collection)". 'Collection' ins not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate using a lambda

```
new Variable<List<string>>("Provider", context => provider)
```

but I'm not sure this is what you want to be doing in the Create method of the activity template factory. This method is going to be called from your designer at design time but surely provider is a runtime concern. Shouldn't you be using something at runtime to go and fetch the provider?

Comment: I try to save the query result in a List<string> in the constructor's activity method. Later, in create method I create a variable as the same type (List<string>) with name as Provider and copy the previous list provider in Provider.

Comment: Your activity actually looks like an activity template. In an activity template you can only supply the structure of a section of workflow not actual code. For that you will need to implement a CodeActivity/AsyncCodeActivity/NativeActivity that will fetch the list of strings from the database.

Comment: Can I do SimpleNativeActivity : NativeActivity, IActivityTemplateFactory in the same class isn't it?